# Measure max rate of ADC samples in one second

Tags: arduino

Does anyone have a code snippet to measure the max rate of ADC samples achievable in one second. I understand there is a millis()function in Arduino.

```
unsigned long start, finsihed, elapsed;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorVal = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorVal);
  Serial.println("Start...");
  start = millis();
  Serial.println("Finished");
  elapsed = finished - start;
  Serial.print(elapsed);
  Serial.println(" milliseconds elapsed");
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: The datasheet says 15kSps. Is that value no good for you?

Comment: Just practice really and learning. Thats all I want to know for.

Comment: Just set the max. rate and check for overflows. Then lower using bisection until overflows just disappear. Reading ADC samples in a loop is a bad idea most times as the samples will hardly be equally spaced. For the remaing use-cases, the max. rate is of no actual interrest, as they are not equally spaced anyway.

Comment: Sure, use millis().  And no, you can't measure A/D rate, you can only measure reporting rate.  Which depends heavily on the serial port baudrate.  Which is fine, that's the only one you really care about.  Also a good reason to do this on the other end of the wire.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out the maximum number of times you can process and ADC in one second you should probably try something besides printing out a value every time!

For instance you could use a for loop that counts one every 10,000 times you have read e.g.

```
start = millis()
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
     analogRead(A0);

}
finish = millis()
total = start - finish
print("This trail took ");
print(total);
print(" miliseconds!");
```

Coincidentally 10,000 is the number of times the data sheet [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead) tells you the arduino can run analog read a second!